# Free software for creating ISO images from files or discs?

Tags: windows, gratis, optical-media, iso

Is there a good, free software for creating ISO images from files or discs?

No shareware or "free" software with greatly limited functionality, please!

Edit: For Windows

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention the operating system for which you're looking for.

Comment: As he suggests BurnAware Free, which is a Windows product, I'm guessing he is on Windows.

Comment: If you don't need to create ISOs > 300MB, [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com) will do the trick. I don't list it as an answer, because technically this is "limited functionality" -- but if it works for your specific purpose, knock yourself out!

I paid for the full version (~US$30) and it's proven quite handy; it can make bootable ISOs and is very flexible in what it can read and write.

Answer (score 3):

#### [InfraRecorder](http://infrarecorder.org/)

I'm assuming from your answer that your OS is Windows. On that, I use InfraRecorder. It:

- Has full-featured CD/DVD burning and image recording tools
- Is free and open source, not a shareware or freemium.

Answer (score 3):

You may try [Brasero](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Brasero) If you run Linux.

If you are running Windows as OS then I recommend the lightweight [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) is a powerful 100% free tool for burning CDs DVDs.

If you don't like or have already tried ImgBurn the there is another one [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/). It is also pretty lightweight and satisfactory in looks.(If you don't like the ImgBurn's interface)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of PowerShell scripts that can do that:

[New-ISOFile function](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/New-ISOFile-function-a8deeffd)
[image]

There's [ISO Creator Tool](http://blog.apps.id.au/?p=5321). It's really well done for a PowerShell solution:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I personally don't create ISOs very much. If I have to create one, I use [CDBurnerXP](https://cdburnerxp.se/), which was already mentioned. For mounting I like to use [Virtual CloneDrive](https://www.elby.ch/de/products/vcd.html). It's very lightweight, simple and integrates itself seamlessly into Windows.

If you're looking for a program that can create **and** mount ISOs I can recommend [DAEMON Tools Lite](https://www.daemon-tools.cc/products/dtLite).

Comment: Is this **free**? No, it is not.

Comment: @Daniel I was confused myself, because I still have an old version installed. If you scroll down you can choose a **free license** ;)

Comment: There is no free license of CloneDVD on the web site.

Comment: @Daniel Oh, I'm sorry. They must've changed it somehow. You can only get a 21 day free trial [here](https://www.elby.ch/de/download.html).

Comment: Please delete the answer. It's misleading.

Comment: @Daniel I updated my answer.

Comment: Now it doesn't even answer my question anymore.

Comment: @Daniel What do you mean? CDBurnerXP and DAEMON Tools Lite can both create ISO images from files or discs.